# Need help in executing SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are two queries with results, I need to run one query to get same result.

```
1-Total slots
2-created Date
3-start date
4-end date
5-Unused Slots
```

First Query:-

```
SELECT COUNT( id ) as total_slots , 
       created_date, MIN( DATE ) as start_date , 
       MAX( DATE ) as end_date 
FROM slots 
GROUP BY created_date;
```

Query 1(Result)

[Here is image with query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqL4N.png)

#### Can I get unused slots in same query as I am getting from below query?

But here

```
SELECT COUNT( id ) AS unused 
FROM slots
WHERE user_id =0 
AND created_date =  '2016-10-01 20:20:20'
```

Result Query with created date 2016-10-01 20:20:20

```
unused  
79

SELECT COUNT( id ) AS unused 
FROM slots 
WHERE user_id =0 
AND created_date =  '2016-10-01 20:24:45'
```

Result Query with created date 2016-10-01 20:24:45

```
unused  
51
```

Comment: @what is your expected/desired output ? as both tables are different and do es not relates to each other

Comment: Its only one table named "slots" as "vb_slots" is just a mistake. here is image URL for expected result. https://postimg.org/image/ol75wyq6v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
   COUNT( id ) as total_slots, 
   created_date, 
   MIN( DATE ) as start_date, 
   MAX( DATE ) as end_date,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id = 0 THEN 1 END) as unused_slots
FROM slots 
GROUP BY created_date;
```

Comment: wow its amazing exactly as required, can you please explain about "CASE WHEN user_id = 0 THEN 1 END"?

Comment: The COUNT aggregate does not count NULL so the CASE expression says "if user_id is 0 then return 1" since there are no other defined cases NULL will be returned for any other record whose user_id is not 0. i.e. for every record whose user_id is 0 will be tallied in the COUNT.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated for help!